# Add Values in an Array - Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic

I am using the following `For loop` to display all files in a folder excluding files with an `.asp` extension.

I want to add the filename to an array, so that `objFileItem.Name` gets added to each element in `tmpArray`.

I tried using `tmpArray(k) = objFileItem.Name` but its throwing an error.

```
For Each objFileItem In objFolderContents
    strFileExtension = LCase(Mid(objFileItem.Name, _
        InStrRev(objFileItem.Name, ".", -1, 1) + 1))
        If strFileExtension <> "asp"  Then
            strImages=strImages & objFileItem.Name
        end if

Next
```

Comment: "But it is throwing an error", perhaps you'd like to share the error that it is throwing. Further more I see no refernce to `tmpArray` in the code you have provided.

Comment: Where do you initialize "strImages"?

Comment: @Diodeus it doesn't need to be initialized, VBScript will assume it's an empty string on the first occurrence of `strImages=strImages & objFileItem.Name`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have reasonable amount of items (less than 100) just use dynamic array like this:

```vbs
Dim tmpArray()
ReDim tmpArray(-1)
For Each objFileItem In objFolderContents
    strFileExtension = LCase(Mid(objFileItem.Name, _
        InStrRev(objFileItem.Name, ".", -1, 1) + 1))
    If strFileExtension <> "asp"  Then
        strImages = strImages & objFileItem.Name
        ReDim Preserve tmpArray(UBound(tmpArray) + 1)
        tmpArray(UBound(tmpArray)) = objFileItem.Name
    End If
Next

'show array items:
Response.Write("Total of " & (UBound(tmpArray) + 1) & " files:<br />")
For k=0 To UBound(tmpArray)
    Response.Write(tmpArray(k) & "<br />")
Next

'when done with the array, release resources to prevent memory leak:
Erase tmpArray
```

Comment: hey buddy, any chance you could drop my Q here a look : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55831029/update-sql-server-with-html-input-within-a-while-loop-asp-classic/55831850#55831850